# Convert firebase timestamp to snowflake timestamp

Tags: sql, firebase, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have a raw table from firebase in snowflake. All the information that I need is in the field "Data" (JSON). Because of that, I created a view to extract all the data in deferents columns.
I use json_extract_path_text(data, 'createdAt') to extract the createdAt timestamp. But, that function converts my data in a string like: `{"_nanoseconds":248000000,"_seconds":1641850613}`.

I want to convert them to TIMESTAMP format in snowflake. Is there anyway to do it?
I try with TO_TIMESTAMP but doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

[TO_TIMESTAMP(integer)](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/to_timestamp.html) could be used:

> If the format of the input parameter is a string that contains an integer:
>
> After the string is converted to an integer, the integer is treated as a number of seconds, milliseconds, microseconds, or nanoseconds after the start of the Unix epoch (1970-01-01 00:00:00.000000000 UTC).
>
> If the integer is less than 31536000000 (the number of milliseconds in a year), then the value is treated as a number of seconds.
>
> If the value is greater than or equal to 31536000000 and less than 31536000000000, then the value is treated as milliseconds.
>
> If the value is greater than or equal to 31536000000000 and less than 31536000000000000, then the value is treated as microseconds.
>
> If the value is greater than or equal to 31536000000000000, then the value is treated as nanoseconds.

```
SELECT TO_TIMESTAMP('1644007937');
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: To add more information: I have a raw table from firebase in snowflake. All the information that I need is in the field "Data". I use json_extract_path_text(data, 'createdAt') to extract the createdAt timestamp. But, that function converts my data in a string like: {"_nanoseconds":248000000,"_seconds":1641850613}. The question is: how I cant convert this string in a timestamp?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the TO_TIMESTAMP function as shown below but bear in mind that this works for seconds, as [by default the timestamps in Snowflake will be treated as seconds](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/to_timestamp.html#usage-notes) (Deprecation Warning: Future versions of Snowflake might automatically interpret stringified integer values as seconds, rather than as milliseconds, microseconds, or nanoseconds.). For nanoseconds, you would need to divide it first by 10e9:

```
select  to_timestamp(json_extract_path_text('{"_nanoseconds":248000000,"_seconds":1641850613}', '_seconds'));--2022-01-10 21:36:53.000

select to_timestamp(json_extract_path_text('{"_nanoseconds":248000000,"_seconds":1641850613}', '_nanoseconds')/1000000000);--1970-01-01 00:00:00.248
```